# Size of Vector yielding negative on substraction

Tags: c++

**Demo Code**:
This is the driver code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1={} ;
    cout<<v1.size()-1;
}
```

**Output**: Upon execution

```
18446744073709551615
```

**EDIT**

We can simply use `static_cast<int>(v1.size()-1)` to rule out unsigned behaviour and overflow.

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is positive

Comment: Yes this is obvious to some folk, but do note the question is well-asked, with compilable code and behaviour documented. It's difficult to search for a duplicate on this if you don't already know the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba FWIW, if you google *vector size minus 1 garbage c++* the dupe target is the very first result in google.  To me that's not too difficult of a search to come up with.

Comment: @NathanOliver True and you found an excellent duplicate (I think you should be able to upvote the dupe spotter for +2, but that’s another matter of course.)

Comment: "We can simply [cast to `int`] to rule out unsigned behaviour and overflow" No, you can't! You cast the result of the subtraction to `int`. So, you cast `0u - 1` to `int` and just so happen to get the implementation-defined result that `0u - 1` means the max unsigned value, i.e. an all-`1` unsigned bit pattern, which also means signed `-1` on your system. That doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @underscore_d: have you ever in your life seen a C++-capable computer that treats an all-`1` bit pattern as something other than `-1`? Because I haven't.

Comment: @TonyK No, but (until C++20, which mandates two's complement) the language doesn't require that, and that IMO is worth pointing out. I don't like relying on implementation-defined behaviour, even if all extant implementations define it the same way. :-)